How to add cookie to native app using wdio or appium js
I am using wdio with appium for native app automation for both Android and iOS platforms
I want to set some custom cookie into my native app for automation
but I dont have access to modify the native app data

Approach -1

tried to use browser.setCookies() method
await browser.setCookies(
 {
  name: 'NativeAppcookie',
  value: 'Cookie_value',
  secure: true,
})

but I am getting error
WARN webdriver: Request failed with status 405 due to Method is not implemented


but browser.setCookies() works for mobile browser as expected and facing issue only with mobile native app

Approach -2

added custom data to the appium capability
capabilities: {
                platformName: 'iOS',
                    platformVersion: '14.5',
                    deviceName: 'iPhone 12',
                    app: '/path/to/your/app',
                    automationName: 'XCUITest', 
                'appium:customData': {
                    'cookies': [
                        {
                            name: 'cookie_name',
                            value: 'cookie_value',
                            path: '/',
                            domain: 'test_domain.com',
                            secure: true
                        },
                    ]
                }
            }

but the expected behaviour for setting the cookie is not seen when I launch the native application
